# Как найти точку пересечения луча и плоскости треугольника?

Tags: геометрия, 3d

*Хочу разобраться с 3D-моделированием, соответственно, реализация на готовых движках на данный момент совершенно не интересует.*

Действую по стандартной стратегии: выпустить луч от камеры в направлении пикселя на экране, затем найти точку пересечения луча и плоскости, в которой лежит полигон (треугольник). Для нахождения уравнения плоскости полигона хочу использовать метод Гаусса, луч задаю пересечением двух плоскостей (2 коэффициента назначаю сам, остальные 2 ищу тем же методом Гаусса - нахожу уравнение плоскости, в которой лежит луч, повторяю операцию с другими начальными коэффициентами - получаю уравнение другой плоскости). Далее просто подставляю в матрицу 3х3 коэффициенты трех плоскостей и нахожу точку их пересечения.

Проблема заключается в поиске уравнения плоскости полигона в случае, когда эта плоскость проходит через точку (0, 0, 0), так как я изначально выбираю коэффициент D = 1 (для такой плоскости он всегда будет равен 0). Не знаете ли вы, как обычно решают эту проблему?

---

**UPDATE:** Вот решение, которое получилось у меня:

Вместо поиска уравнений плоскостей, действительно проще работать сразу с векторами.
Пусть плоскость задается тремя точками: A, B, C. А прямая двумя: D, E. Точка T - пересечение прямой с плоскостью. Можно воспользоваться двумя свойствами векторов:

1. Смешанное произведение компланарных векторов = 0
2. Векторное произведение коллинеарных векторов = нулевому вектору

Вот так получается матрица координат точки T:

[image]

Дальше можно решать тем же методом Гаусса.
При таком подходе матрица не будет иметь решения методом Гаусса только в двух случаях: когда прямая лежит в плоскости и когда они параллельны

Comment: Маленькие системы лучше решать Крамером.

Comment: Если есть треугольник, то есть к нему нормаль и точка в плоскости треугольника. Прямая заданная параметрически переводится в 1D проекцией на нормаль. Отыскивается параметр в котором прямая пересекает плоскость (линейное уравнение). Всё.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пользуюсь вот таким методом (емнип основан на https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/25082/3644) для нахождения точки пересечения луча и треугольника (без плоскостей):

```
function RayTriangleIntersect(const aRay: TKMVertex3Ray; const V1, V2, V3: TKMVertex3; out aPoint: TKMVertex3): Boolean;
var
  rayDir, E1, E2, PV, QV, TV: TKMVertex3;
  T, U, V, Det, InvDet: Single;
begin
  Result := False;

  rayDir := aRay.Endpoint - aRay.Start;

  E1 := V2 - V1;
  E2 := V3 - V1;
  PV := VectorCrossProduct(rayDir, E2);
  Det := VectorDotProduct(E1, PV);

  // Skip if Ray is parallel to triangle
  if Abs(Det) < 0.00001 then
    Exit;

  InvDet := 1 / Det;
  TV := aRay.Start - V1;
  U := VectorDotProduct(TV, PV) * InvDet;

  if (U >= 0) and (U <= 1) then
  begin
    QV := VectorCrossProduct(TV, E1);
    V := VectorDotProduct(rayDir, QV) * InvDet;
    if (V >= 0) and (U + V <= 1) then
    begin
      T := VectorDotProduct(E2, QV) * InvDet;
      if T > 0.00001 then
      begin
        aPoint := TKMVertex3.NewLerp(aRay.Start, aRay.Endpoint, T);
        Result := True;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Не поясните, какой физический смысл PV?

Comment: Первое применение CrossProduct (`PV`) - это перпендикуляр к лучу и одной из сторон треугольника. Если этот перпендикуляр перпендикулярен и другой стороне треугольника (DotProduct в районе 0) - значит луч параллелен плоскости в которой треугольник лежит.

Comment: OK, это понятно. Неясно было, как это приводит к вычислению полезной величины Det, однако увидел, что это ж смешанное произведение получается .

Comment: Я когда разбирался и тестировал это все проверял и помнил, а сейчас, последние лет 12, это просто полезная ф-ия из личной математической библиотечки. Кажется ТС примерно как надо все понял и нарисовал.

Comment: Ну да, я знаю, что в геометрии, когда начинаешь оптимизировать и упрощать шаги, может получиться слабопонятная вещь.

Answer (score -1):

Если надо просто вернуть да/нет пересечения луча с треугольником, то это одно, а если и координаты точки пересечения с треугольником или объектом с меш сеткой, то придётся усложнить код. В GLScene для этого есть вся необходимая иерархия 3д объектов и методов. Вот пример из
..\GLScene\Examples\Demos\collisions\RayBox\fRayBoxD.pas
нахождения пересечения луча с кубом -

```
         RayDir := AffineVectorMake(Random * 2 - 1, Random * 2 - 1, Random * 2 - 1);
  NormalizeVector(RayDir);

  GLLines1.Nodes.Clear;
  GLLines1.Nodes.AddNode(RayStart);
  GLLines1.Nodes.AddNode(VectorAdd(RayStart, VectorScale(RayDir, 8)));
  GLPoints1.Positions.Clear;
  GLPoints1.Positions.Add(RayStart);
  GLPoints1.Positions.Add(BoxPos);
  GLPoints1.Positions.Add(VectorSubtract(BoxPos, afScale));
  GLPoints1.Positions.Add(VectorAdd(BoxPos, afScale));

  if RayCastBoxIntersect(RayStart, RayDir, VectorSubtract(BoxPos, afScale),
    VectorAdd(BoxPos, afScale), @iPnt) then
  begin
    Label1.Caption := Format('Intersect point: %.3f %.3f %.3f', [iPnt.X, iPnt.Y, iPnt.Z]);
    GLPoints1.Positions.Add(iPnt);
    beep;
  end
  else
    Label1.Caption := 'no intersection';
```

Т.е. нашли точку пересечения, для сложных объектов в иерархии, состоящих  из многих треугольников типа TGLMesh, TGLFreeForm, TGLActor есть и встроенные в классы методы нахождения пересечений помимо коллизии с другими объектами.

Comment: "реализация на готовых движках на данный момент совершенно не интересует" и математика из GLScene. Вот это поворот!